# How can I hook an EventListener to an Event class and its subclasses?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Suppose I can add an `EventListener` to an `EventDispatcher` based on the event's  `Class<T>` like:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Set<EventListener>> listenerSets;

public <E extends Event<E>> void addListener(EventListener<E> listener, Class<E> eventClass) {
    Set<EventListener> listeners = listenerSets.get(eventClass);
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

To find any added listeners for a specific `Event`, I use the event's class as key to retrieve the set of all listeners hooked to it.

```
private void fire(Event event) {
    Set<EventListener> listeners = listenerSets.get(event.getClass());
    // ...
}
```

Now suppose I have an abstract superclass for related events, for instance `OrderChanged` as a superclass of `OrderLineAdded`. Some listeners might only want to know when an order changes, without needing to know specifics.

Can I register on those superclasses in some way and trigger the listeners in case a subclass event occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to just iterate over the `listenerSets` and find all listeners registered for superclasses of `OrderChanged` and notify on them.

```
private void fire(OrderLineAdded event) {
    listenerSets.entrySet().stream()
    .filter( e -> e.getKey().isAssignableFrom( event.getClass() ) )
    .forEach( e -> {
        Set<EventListener> events = e.getValue();
    } );
}
```

Of course you need to `addListener` for `OrderChanged` beforehand.